# Parallel.ForEach Doesn't Like IList

Tags: c#, list, parallel.foreach

The following code does not compile.

```
IList configurationItems = dataSourceService.Get(configurationClass);
Parallel.ForEach(configurationItems, configurationItem =>
{...}
```

Parallel.ForEach complains, "The type arguments for method 'ForEach(IEnumerable,Action)' cannot be inferred from the usage.  Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

I have tried every form of cast I can think of and none of them works.  My attempts to dig into the overloads for Parallel.ForEach have been likewise unsuccessful.

Comment: can you use a `IList<T>`?

Comment: Not sure why this has 4 votes when the [doco](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx) clearly states the requirement of `IEnumerable<T>` which `IList` doesn't immediately imply.  Use `IList<T>` as Daniel states

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you make the `IList` an `IList<T>`?

The problem here is that every invocation of `Parallel.ForEach` is actually `Parallel.ForEach<T>` - a generic method with a type argument. The C# compiler is pretty good at guessing type arguments when it's possible to. This method has a signature `ForEach<T>(IEnumerable<T>, Action<T>)`. As long as you provide an `IEnumerable<T>` the compiler knows what the `T` is for the whole invocation. `IList` does not implement `IEnumerable<T>`, just `IEnumerable`, so the compiler can't work out what type argument to use for the method. This is the complaint here.

Alternatively, if stuck with an `IList` you can use

```
Parallel.ForEach<T>(configurationItems.OfType<T>(), (T item) => ....);
```

Where T is the actual type you want.
I suspect that you won't need the type argument on the ForEach method though. You possibly won't need to specify the type of the lambda expression argument either. `OfType<T>` will probably be enough for the compiler to infer the rest.

Comment: The suggested adornments result in an error condition on the collection parameter, "Cannot convert from 'method group' to IEnumerable<T>"

Comment: Please show the exact code you used in attempting to fix (feel free to edit your question to show attempts as it is easier to format there). The error makes me guess that you supplied the method as the argument rather than the result of invoking it.

Comment: (try adding parentheses after the `OfType<T>`)

Comment: Thank you.  Not sure how I didn't happen to hard cast the list.

IList<Object> configurationItems = dataSourceService.Get(configurationClass) as IList<Object>;

Comment: Instead of `OfType<T>()`, you should use `Cast<T>()`. That way, it's clear you're not filtering out items of other types. And if you make a mistake, you get an exception instead of incorrect results.